# Getting the sum of an array, saving to core data, and starting from the sum once app is reopened?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm kind of stuck on what I would assume is a simple solution and I just can't figure out what to do.

I'm basically creating an expenses application for iOS and I've gotten to the point where I need to add up all the total expenses from my UITableView list.

```
 private var items:[Shoe] = []
 private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 private var managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

 // Start of calculating the gain or loss for the individual item
        let buyDouble: Double? = Double(buyToSave)
        let sellDouble: Double? = Double(sellToSave)
        let feeDouble: Double? = Double(feeToSave)
        let feeInt = 1-(feeDouble!/100)
        let profit = (feeInt*sellDouble!) - buyDouble!
        let profitNSNumb = profit as NSNumber
        let profitString = currencyFormatter.string(from: profitNSNumb)

        let shoe = Shoe(entity: Shoe.entity(), insertInto: self.managedContext)
        shoe.name = nameToSave
        shoe.buyPrice = buyToSave
        shoe.sellPrice = sellToSave
        shoe.size = sizeToSave
        shoe.fee = feeToSave
        shoe.profitLoss = profitString
        shoe.quantity = Int16(shoeQuantity)
        shoe.sum = shoe.sum + profit

 // Save the data
        self.appDelegate.saveContext()

        // Reloads the UITableView
        self.shoeList.reloadData()
        self.viewDidLoad()
```

I believe my logic is correct right? Im not sure why I keep start at $0 every time I quit my application and open it back up again?

ex:

ITEM #.......EXPENSE

Item 1.......$100

Item 2.......$200

Item 3.......$50

Total Expense: $350

Then when I close the app and start it up again:

ITEM #.......EXPENSE

Item 1.......$100

Item 2.......$200

Item 3.......$50

Total Expense: $350 <---- I want it to start at $350 and not $0

Comment: Is your `Shoe` entity completely made up of String attributes even though many of them are numbers? I'm asking because your code looks strange to me and you might be making things harder than necessary for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call .save() on context in order to save the changes you made (in this case created a new Shoe object).

Try saving it like this:

```
 do {          
   try self.managedContext.save()       
  } catch {       
   print("Failed saving")
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include that part, but yes I did save it. Lemme add it to the original post